# Display records in a table with NextID and PrevID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some of following fields in the quotestable : quotesid is the primarykey

```
 ┌──────────┬────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │ QuotesID │ QuotesDesc │ QuotesTags                                 │
 ├──────────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┤
 │ 75       │ Quotes 1   │ Leadership, Integrity, Values              │
 │ 100      │ Quotes 2   │ Leadership, Faith                          │
 │ 102      │ Quotes 3   │ HeartPower, Motivation, Leadership         │
 │ 105      │ Quotes 4   │ Mercy, Power, Military, Leadership         │
 │ 209      │ Quotes 5   │ Compassion, Confidence, Leadership, Family │
 └──────────┴────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I have a query like this `select  * from quotestable where contains (QuotesTags, 'Leadership')`

My requirement is in my webpage if i display the quotes having quoteid = 102, i want the next 3 quotes to be displayed in an iframe. ie., 105, 209, 75

if my webpage displays quotes = 209 i want the next 3 quotes as 75,100,102 (if it ends start from the beginning)

Also I need two extra columns which will have NextQuoteID and PrevQuoteID in the resultant query which will point to next and previous quotesid. I donot know how to put these extra two columns in the final query.

I am using sql-server 2008 r2 version.

Comment: It is unclear how you hope to make a webpage with an iFrame when you only have SQL Server tagged.

Answer (score 1):

Answer only for SQL Server 2012+

We did not know it was SQL Server 2008 until 2 hours after this answer.
It could be done with sub-queries if anyone is bothered.
I'm not because I got a downvote for not knowing what version the answer was required for

```
SELECT TOP 4
    QuotesID = SortQuotesID % 1000000, 
    QuotesDesc, QuotesTags,
    NextQuoteID = (LEAD(SortQuotesID) OVER (ORDER BY SortQuotesID))% 1000000,
    PrevQuoteID = (LEAG(SortQuotesID) OVER (ORDER BY SortQuotesID))% 1000000
FROM
    (
    select SortQuotesID = QuotesID, QuotesDesc, QuotesTags                                 
    from quotestable where contains (QuotesTags, 'Leadership')
    UNION ALL
    select SortQuotesID = QuotesID+1000000, QuotesDesc, QuotesTags                                 
    from quotestable
    ) X
ORDER BY 
    SortQuotesID
```

Comment: whats this? select SortQuotesID = QuotesID+1000000 . This also doesnot address the nextQuotesID and PrevQuotesID issue.

Comment: Have you tried it? You need SortQuotesID to wrap around to the beginning as per your requirement. nextQuotesID and PrevQuotesID require SQL Server 2012+

Comment: I am using sql-server 2008

Comment: Well, I'm not spending time giving you a solution for a version of SQL that is 10 years and 4 versions old. What I gave you is perfectly valid as a solution. That you told us *after* I answered: no-one else has you notice